# What is the threshold we should set when connect with bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

what is the ideal threshold value of RSSI to establish connection with bluetooth in didDiscoverPeripheral delegate method.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for keyboard and mouse usage on a MAC. It might be different threshold for different devices.

```
-40 to -55 is a very strong connection
-70 and above represents a good connection
-100 and below represents a bad connection
-110 and below is almost unusable
```